# Excel If Statement- Need to show "blank" in blank cell

Tags: excel, if-statement

```
     Cell A1=  Target Date - 1/1/13
     Cell B1=  Completion Date - 1/15/13
     Cell C1=  Returns "Closed within 30 days"
```

> I am trying to use the If Statement to return the word "blank" if a cell in column C1 is empty.
>
> > Here is what I have so far.

```
      =IF(B1>A1+30,"",Closed within 30 days")
```

Thank you

Comment: I think It should worked ..

Comment: You're looking for `ISBLANK()`.

Comment: when the formula his a blank cell it is returning "Closed within 30 days" I need it to return "blank" when the cell in empty

Comment: please show the ISBLANK() string

Comment: @user2326092 .. C1 is empty .. do you mean no formula in there or result "" from formula .. ?

Comment: result "" from formula

Answer (score 2):

> I am trying to use the If Statement to return the word "blank" if a
>   cell in column C1 is empty.

Try `= If(IsEmpty(C1),"Blank","Not Blank"))`

Answer (score 0):

Actually I think I understand your question now; what you want is when cell A1 or B1 is blank it should return "Blank".

```
=IF(OR(ISBLANK(A1),ISBLANK(B1)),"Blank",IF(B1>A1+30,"","Closedwithin30days"))
```